# App does not render when using browserHistory instead of hashHistory in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router in my current project:

```
const store = Redux.createStore(bomlerApp);
const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null,
                this.props.children
            )
        )
    }
})
var rootElement =
    React.createElement(ReactRedux.Provider, {store: store},
        React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, {history: ReactRouter.browserHistory},
            React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, { path: '/', component: App },
                React.createElement(ReactRouter.IndexRoute, { component: Home })
            )
        )
    )
ReactDOM.render(rootElement, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

This does not work. The app does not render at all and I don't get any error messages.

However, if I use ReactRouter.hashHistory instead, the app works.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: [Your server must be ready to handle real URLs. When the app first loads at `/` it will probably work, but as the user navigates around and then hits refresh at `/accounts/23` your web server will get a request to `/accounts/23`. You will need it to handle that URL and include your JavaScript application in the response.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server)

Comment: Not even the / is working

Comment: Have you removed the `/#/` part from the url? Also any error messages?

Comment: @Kujira yes I have removed it and no error messages.

Comment: Oh my oh my. Actually my app is at domain.com/app, so when I change to browserHistory the relative path doesn't work, of course.

Answer (score 0):

- Server Configuration: the browser history setup can generate real
  looking urLs without reloading the page. But what happens if the user
  refreshes or bookmarks on a deep nested urL? these urLs are
  dynamically generated at the browser; they do not correspond to real
  paths on the server, and since any urL will always hit the server on
  the first request, it will likely return a page not Found error.
- To implement the browser history setup, you need to import the
  createBrowserHistory method from the History library. You can then
  invoke it, passing the generated browser history configuration as the
  history prop of the Router component
- ***> to work with browser history setup, you need to make rewrite

  > configurations on your server, so when the user hits /some-path on the
  >   browser, the server will serve index page from where react router will
  >   render the right view.***

Comment: This is not answering the question why hashHistory works but browserHistory doesn't at all.